# what is the best practice for aligning html

Tags: html, css

## html code

```
<div id="signup">
    <p>
        <label>Frist Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    <p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    <p>
    <p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    <p>
    <p>
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    <p>
    <p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password"/>
    <p>
    <p>
        <label>Re Password</label>
        <input type="password"/>
    <p>
</div>
```

and this is css

## css

```
#signup{
    width: 860px;
    background-color: white;
    border:  1px black solid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#signup p label{
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: #0986e3;
}
#signup p input{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0.4em;
}
```

if u run this code u will see the input files right and left , and that is not good , i can correct this problems using div or li , but i want the best practice for doing that , i want the input filds to be exaclty below each other
,this is the code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/EfBD7/

Comment: You can fix that with float and clear

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to active, -1

Comment: What are you actualy trying ot do? You explain what it does, but not what you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want to input filed to be exaclty below each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I did it how I would do it.  I stripped out the p and some css to make text right side. but you can of course add display:inline-block;width:300px; to the label and swap the label and input locations in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#signup{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border:  1px black solid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#signup label{
    font:12px arial;
    color: #0986e3;
}
#signup input{
    margin:10px;
    width: 300px;
    padding 0.4em;
}
#signup input[type=button]{
    margin:10px;
    width: 80px;
    padding 0.4em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="signup">
    <input type="text"/>
    <label>Frist Name</label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <label>Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="password"/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password"/>
    <label>Re Password</label>
    <input type="button" value="click me!" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very beutifull man, but i am wondering how the lables not going on the same line becuse u didn't use P

Comment: it is because they are confined to the width of the div,

Comment: i add a button , when the user clicked it , i want to sumit that values to the database , but please look how the button appear
http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/BMeAj/3/

Comment: I updated the answer above with the css solution.  also here http://jsfiddle.net/BMeAj/4/

Comment: really thank you man , i accept ur answer , but the last think , see this 
http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/Vt4jn/1/
the button still in the left :(

Comment: Here you go.  You have a 200px left margin on your label that needs to go, and set your button margin to what I have.  10px 10px 10px 350px, goes top right bottom left

Comment: The p's weren't exactly appropriate, but neither is nothing at all, you should probably use a ul and li elements, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/27rBF/.

Answer (score 4):

[Make the labels display as block elements](http://jsfiddle.net/EfBD7/2/). That way, you can set it's width. But you still need them to be inline. You need to apply either `float:left`, or `display:inline-block` so they act inline as well as block.

```
#signup p label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}

/*or*/
#signup p label{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
```

If you want to support older browsers, then use the `float:left`. If you target new browsers, then `display:inline-block` is better. [If you use the float approach](http://jsfiddle.net/EfBD7/5/), add this to the CSS to clear the float:

```
#signup p{
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the label a definite width, like:

```
#signup p label{
  padding: 0.4em;
  color: #0986e3;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use table , might help your cause , [see the example](http://jsfiddle.net/7DqnY/) , sorry for not aligning the markup well.